# Matching a string with an array key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying how to figure something out for my website.
This is not my code just an example to make it easier to understand what i mean.

Lets say i have an array like this:

```
$services = array(
    Marketing  => marketing:342343423423,
    Sales => sales:779876786,
)
```

And i have a form on my website. I can get the posted values with a POST request.

The POST request can for example look like this

```
$_POST['service_request']
```

Now what i want to know is how to do the next:

if `$_POST['service_request']` matches one of the array keys inside `$services` then print the relevant value of this array key.

So lets say an user fills my form, and his service request is marketing then i want to check if this service request exists inside the `$service` variable and if it exist print the value.

Comment: [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `key_exists` function of php.

```
 if(key_exists($_POST['service_request'],$services)){
   //exists, perform rest of the logic here.
 }
```

**Update**: it's an alias of `array_key_exists` so both are basically same.

Comment: Nope it's an alias @Jay

Comment: My bad @clive. Not finished with my first cup of coffee yet ;-)

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. 
Normally when i want to print the value of an array i do it like print_r($test['key']) can the part inside [] be a POST request? for example print_r($test[$_POST['myfield']]) ?

Comment: ` []` indicates array, `$test[$_POST['myfield']]` means key (value of `$_POST['myfield']`) in `$test` array

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**:
Code below can give an exception if the key isn't set. You should use the key_exists, given in the other answer. Or change it to:

```
if ( isset($services[$_POST['service_request']]) ) {
    echo $services[$_POST['service_request']];
}
```

This code will print the value from the array with the given key:

```
$value = $services[$_POST['service_request']];
echo (isset($value) ? $value : '');
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: CAN GIVE EXECPTION OF UNDEFINED OFFSET if value doesn't exist

Comment: Forgot about that, my bad.